# Close dialog box after a message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i close the dialog box after displaying a message for 3 seconds:

My code:-

```
$('#response').html("<p>message. 
</p>").fadeIn('slow').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow').
mydialog.dialog.close();
```

Thanks

Comment: Can enter your code into jsfiddle.net , so we can help you.

Comment: I have a form inside my dialog box. When i submit the form, i just want to close my dialog box after displaying a successful message for 3 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#response').html("<p>message. 
</p>").fadeIn('slow').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow',function() {
   mydialog.dialog.close();
  });
```

Comment: I have tried this but not working, am getting this error "undefined is not a function"

Comment: the error is propably from this line `mydialog.dialog.close();` i don't know what function you are calling

Comment: if you want to hide a dialog use the id/class of the dialog `$('.dialog').hide();`

Comment: Worked! when i changed the code mydialog.dialog.close() to $('#id').dialog('close');

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
$('#response').html("<p>message. 
 </p>").fadeIn('slow').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');

 setInterval(function(){  mydialog.dialog.close(); }, 3000);
```